# Need to add text using adapter

Tags: android

Need to add text's and image's using adapter as shown below, image and text should passed from adapter (not from XML file), As I am new to android please share code.

Comment: "as shown below". Where?

Comment: do you mean `TextView` and `ImageView`?

Comment: yes need to add both

Comment: Go read a book or something, this is not the place for this type of question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add a `TextView` and a `ImageView` programmatically in the adapter you can do it as that:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //create cell layout
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        //create your TextView
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        //create your ImageView 
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

        //add them to the cell layout 
        layout.addView(textView);
        layour.addView(imageView);

    }
```

I recommend that you use the `Viewholder` pattern that you can find [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) or just search, it saves memory by reusing views that are already on screen rather than creating a new one every time.